# How to view pubnub signal history?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

PubNub in their docs mentions "Unlike messages, however, signals aren't stored in history for later retrieval—you can only fetch the most recent Signal message from history."

How do I fetch the last signal? PubNub Javascript Docs don't specify any method to fetch it. Methods only for Messages are mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Signals do not support retrieval, you can only retrieve messages. I see the documentation at https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/redux/api-reference/signals is incorrect (this is the redux API docs and looks to be the only source for the text you provided) & we will get that fixed, sorry for the inconvenience.